# Constant null input

Tags: arch-linux, input

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 700 with an Antergos. It appears that there is a constant input about every second, which keeps me from scrolling in the terminal or using tty. This is the output using

```
$ xev
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,  
root 0x153, subw 0x0, time 7416716, (262,3), root:(1124,458),  
state 0x0, keycode 221 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,  
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:   
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:   
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I already tried disabling the Fn lock in the BIOS but it did not help. 
Does anyone know how to fix this or get further information where this input comes from?

Comment: Can you test `sudo modprobe -rv peaq_wmi`?

Comment: @grawity The output is

        `rmmod peaq_wmi 
        rmmod input_polldev`

Comment: I just noticed that your command fixed it, thanks a lot! Do you want to post it as an answer again so I can accept it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux kernel 4.13 introduced the [peaq_wmi](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=13bb0fd5519db658860ce3b3c89a7631a3ed1077) driver, which handles hotkeys on PEAQ tablets (specifically the "Dolby" button on PEAQ PMM C1010).

The driver is loaded for a specific WMI object GUID that's found in the system firmware (in the ACPI tables). Unfortunately, PEAQ firmware developers didn't generate a unique GUID – they just copied one from Microsoft's [sample](https://www.google.com/search?q=ABBC0F6F-8EA1-11D1-00A0-C90629100000) WMI driver.

Also unfortunately, they weren't the only manufacturer to do that – the same WMI GUID can be found in Lenovo firmware, where it of course has a completely different meaning. When the driver gets loaded on an incompatible system, it receives a garbage result and thinks the button is always pressed.

*Also* unfortunately, actual PEAQ firmware doesn't notify the OS whenever the button is pressed; instead the OS has to repeatedly poll for its status. So the driver keeps getting the same garbage result every second.

The driver was recently [fixed](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=3b95206110a2c13076c3a7fa8ddeae36c2dbcf42) to also check the system manufacturer name, and the fix should reach stable kernels (4.14.x, 4.13.x) soon. In the mean time, you can remove the module using:

```
modprobe -r peaq_wmi
```

and/or blacklist it via `/etc/modprobe.d` or by using the kernel parameter:

```
modprobe.blacklist=peaq_wmi
```

---

In the future, to debug such problems use tools which report individual input devices; for example, `evemu-record` or `libinput debug-events`. (The `xinput` tool can also do this inside X11.) This can narrow it down to a specific driver.

<sub>(Or you can go through all Git commits from 4.12 to 4.13 until you find one that makes you think *"this new module looks funny, I wonder what happens when you unload it"*)</sub>